# Action in the controller with readfile, where the name is passed by POST method through ajax call

Tags: php, html, ajax, post, phalcon

This is killing me ... dumbest thing but I dont see the point. First of all I'm using phalcon in the server.
Summarizing I want an anchor run a controller action which is basically a readfile (typical save as... window). This I managed, but what I do not get is run it with an ajax POST method, passing the file name in the call (not in the url). It seems I call the action, but not with the variable or at least doesn't finally show the window ... lets see some code:

```
public function descargarimagenAction(){
//Problem in the call, POST arrived here!
$nombre = $this->request->getPost("nombre");
$extension = "jpg";
$this->view->setRenderLevel(\Phalcon\Mvc\View::LEVEL_NO_RENDER);
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-type: image/' . $extension);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nombre.'"');
readfile("img/".$nombre);
die();
}
```

And the html:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="notificaciones/descargarimagen" onclick="$.post(href,{nombre: 'imagendeprueba.jpg'},function(data){alert('done')});return false">
```

The alert activated, and the POST request to the function too, but the readfile or doesn't work or doesn't answers to the view. Any ideas?
The thing is that by href = "notifications / descargarimagen / imagendeprueba.jpg"  I could download, everything perfect. (instead of getPost use a simple get variable in the functions parameters BTW).

Answer (score 1):

First I recommend you make a dump of what you get for POST to server side,

```
var_dump($this->request->getPost())
die();
```

you can check the result in the developer console from any browser. 
I'm not sure if recive JSON So I recommend that you send the data string mode

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="notificaciones/descargarimagen" onclick="$.post(href,'nombre=imagendeprueba.jpg'},function(data){alert('done')});return false">
```